# How to push in tortoisehg

Tags: push, tortoisehg

i don't know where else to write this problem, since i can't find a forum for TortoiseHg.

I have a problem when I'm pushing my code and files to the remote server. It says that the changes (after they were commited) were pushed successfully onto the remote server but the changes are not visible on the server.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

push does not update Working Directory on push-target. You have to `hg up` in order to get pushed changesets in WorkDir

Or write details: How you detected fact "changes are not visible"